# Constructing a subrange of a list numbers in using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to figure out how to construct a sub-range of integers from a list of integers. For example, if I have the range:

`range = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]`

I wish to construct the sub-range:

```
sub_range
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

Such that if I index into the following matrix:

```
x
array([[0.34, 0.45, 0.12, 0.13, 0.48, 0.65, 0.83, 0.65, 0.86, 1.  , 0.15, 0.53, 0.16, 0.76, 0.17, 0.93, 0.16, 0.1 ],
       [0.12, 0.18, 0.33, 0.19, 0.47, 0.46, 0.89, 0.  , 0.58, 0.33, 0.59, 0.05, 0.81, 0.25, 0.95, 0.43, 0.39, 0.65],
       [0.77, 0.32, 0.98, 0.67, 0.58, 0.19, 0.21, 0.63, 0.86, 0.66, 0.04, 0.56, 0.08, 0.22, 0.39, 0.41, 0.69, 0.91],
       [0.96, 0.52, 0.27, 0.44, 0.53, 0.1 , 0.82, 0.88, 0.41, 0.93, 0.35, 0.18, 0.26, 0.62, 0.6 , 0.57, 0.88, 0.67],
       [0.29, 0.52, 0.12, 0.2 , 0.19, 0.57, 0.41, 0.25, 0.88, 0.45, 0.73, 0.08, 0.37, 0.15, 0.84, 0.83, 0.3 , 0.97],
       [0.15, 0.99, 0.71, 0.07, 0.91, 0.73, 0.52, 0.61, 0.66, 0.08, 0.94, 0.76, 0.96, 0.69, 0.4 , 0.26, 0.92, 0.72]])
```

I'll obtain the desired rows and column ranges.

```
x[0:6:2, sub_range]

array([[0.34, 0.45, 0.12, 0.13, 0.48, 0.65],
       [0.21, 0.63, 0.86, 0.66, 0.04, 0.56,],
       [0.37, 0.15, 0.84, 0.83, 0.3 , 0.97]])
```

What function or functions in Numpy, if any, can accomplish this?

Comment: It's not the `sub_range` you need to tent to, but rather the slice `0:6:2`...

Comment: `x[np.array([0,2,4])[:,None], np.array(subrange)]`.  In other words advanced indexing with a (3,1) and (3,6)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using np.take_along_axis (although it just a somewhat faster loop):

```py
range = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
sub_ranges = np.row_stack(np.array_split(range, 3))
np.take_along_axis(x[0:6:2], sub_ranges, axis=1)
```

output:

```
array([[0.34, 0.45, 0.12, 0.13, 0.48, 0.65],
       [0.21, 0.63, 0.86, 0.66, 0.04, 0.56],
       [0.37, 0.15, 0.84, 0.83, 0.3 , 0.97]])
```